# How to read JSON array from HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, json, servlets, jackson, objectmapper

I am very new to servlet and I am unable to read JSON array from HttpServletRequest

I am sending below JSON to Java

```
page: 1
start: 0
limit: 20
sort: [{"property":"fiscalYear","direction":"DESC"}]
```

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] s=request.getParameterValues("sort");
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
}           System.out.println(s[i]);
```

actual output

```
 [{"property":"fiscalYear","direction":"DESC"}]
```

expected output get values fiscalYear and DESC separately

Comment: Use this to generate a domain model class : https://jsonutils.com/  then  use ObjectMapper to convert the json to an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[getParameterValues(String name)](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues-java.lang.String-)** will return the String array

```
String[] getParameterValues(String name)
```

> Returns an array of String objects containing all of the values the given request parameter has, or null if the parameter does not exist.
>
> If the parameter has a single value, the array has a length of 1.

**[getParameter(String name)](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-)** will return only `String`

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist. Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.
>
> **You should only use this method when you are sure the parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have more than one value, use getParameterValues(java.lang.String).**

Based on this you can go for `getParameter` which returns `JSON` representing string

```
String s=request.getParameter("sort"); // {"property":"fiscalYear","direction":"DESC"}
```

Now use `ObjectMapper` to read parse the `JSON` string

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(s);
String property = jsonNode.get("property").asText();
String direction = jsonNode.get("direction").asText();
```

If it is `Array` of `JsonObjects` `//[{"property":"fiscalYear","direction":"DESC"}]`

```
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(s);
JsonNode node = jsonNode.get(0);
String property = node.get("property").asText();
String direction = node.get("direction").asText();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str=request.getParameterValues("sort");
    //  str=" [{\"property\":\"fiscalYear\",\"direction\":\"DESC\"}]";   
      JSONArray array=new JSONArray(str);
      for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
              JSONObject json_obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println( json_obj.getString("direction"));

      }
}
```

### OUTPUT

DESC

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Object which hold this infor :

```
public class SortDto {

  private String property;
  private String direction;

  // getters, setters, toString() ..
}
```

Then create an `ObjectMapper` like this :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String sortJson = request.getParameter("sort");
// I suppose that sortJson is => {"property":"fiscalYear","direction":"DESC"}
SortDto dto = mapper.readValue(sortJson, SortDto.class);
```

Then you can just override the `toString()` method in your class or call `dto.getProperty()` `dto.getDirection()` to get the values separately.

---

**Note**

I used `request.getParameter("sort")` which return one String instead of `request.getParameterValues("sort")` which return an array of values

Comment: It is an array [ {"property":"fiscalYear","direction":"DESC"}]

Comment: @AnmolDuggal even with `[ {"property":"fiscalYear","direction":"DESC"}]` my solution works fine, I test both of them and both work fine